# Rotating video in UiWebView to landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, orientation

I am attempting to make the youtube video that is in my UIWebView go into landscape but my application is only set to portrait and i don't want anything else to be landscape. I have already tried many things for example supporting landscape and on all the other views returning no to landscape but its not working. My project is a tab based application. If i have to the whole view can rotate and not just the video but if just the youtube video could rotate once its gone into fullscreen(which happens automatically) it would be brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your controller subscribe to the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notification and from the method handling the notification rotate just the `UIWebView` containing the video.

This would be something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
       selector: @selector(handleOrientationChangeNotification:)
           name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

-(void)handleOrientationChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{ 
    UIDeviceOrientation currentDeviceOrientation =  [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if (currentDeviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        webView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotateMake(M_PI_2);
        webView.bounds = (CGRect){480,320};
        webView.center = (CGPoint){240,160};
    } else if (...
       ...
}
```

Comment: thanks but I think I might already of tried that, doesn't that just make the web view rotate and the video once fullscreen go portrait?

Comment: i don't want rotate webview i need to rotate html5 video in the webview .is there any  possibility for that.